# Update fails after repeating deadlocked query in pymssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, deadlock, pymssql

I'm using SQL Server with pymssql, and found that a particularly complicated SELECT query would occasionally be selected as a deadlock victim.  So I wrapped it in a while loop to retry the transaction if that happens, roughly as follows:

```
while True:

    try:

        cursor.execute('SELECT .......')
        count_row = cursor.fetchone();
        break

    except Exception, tec:

        print "Got error: %s" % (tec)
        time.sleep(1)

cursor.execute('UPDATE .........')
self.conn.commit()
```

It seems to work - if the SELECT hits a deadlock then it will pause for a second, retry again and get the right answer.  However every time that occurs the following UPDATE statement always fails with:

```
pymssql.OperationalError: Cannot commit transaction: (3902, 'The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.DB-Lib error message 3902, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

The UPDATE statement isn't in the while loop, so I have no idea why it's failing.  It works fine when the SELECT doesn't hit the deadlock condition, so I think it's something to do with recovering from that error.

Any ideas?

Comment: After playing around a bit, I fixed it by closing and reopening the connection object again when it hits the error condition, but that seems messy.  I would love to know if there's a more official solution.

Comment: it would help if we could see the select statement. It might be that it needs to be optimized. Another solution can be using nolock on the select statement only IF you can afford a dirty read. Need a little more information to help.

Comment: Hi Namphibian!  Thanks!  But I'm not too worried about the deadlock itself - it happens very rarely.  I'm more worried about recovering from the deadlock, and why the update fails after the deadlock hits and yet the retry works.

Comment: The update probably fails because the original transaction of your select query is still open. in case of the deadlock you can try to rollback the transaction before doing anything else.