# How to catch a pymssql deadlock as an exception?

Tags: python, sql-server, database-deadlocks, pymssql

We are getting a deadlocked and losing our connection for some of our data mining work. The challenge is we would like to catch when the Python pymssql module fails due to the deadlock.

```
File "pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:6572)
OperationalError: (1205, 'Transaction (Process ID 113) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 13:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

We have tried wrapping our CURSOR.EXECUTE statement in a try/except but it does not trigger.

```
 try:
    CURSOR.execute(query)
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print "RuntimeError: {0}".format(RuntimeError)
```

We see [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748599/update-fails-after-repeating-deadlocked-query-in-pymssql) on SO of people whose code appears to be catching deadlocks so we are unsure why ours is not catching.

Any suggestions how to catch this deadlock?

When the system fails it would be great to be able to sound off a bullhorn or other alarm to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

```
try:
   CURSOR.execute(query)
except pymssql.InterfaceError as e:
   print "SQL Interface Error: "+str(e)
```

But I'm still waiting for the situation of deadlock to occur, so I am not sure :) Anyway, below will handle ALL pymssql errors, INCLUDING the 1205 deadlock:

```
try:
   CURSOR.execute(query)
except pymssql.Error as e:
   print "SQL Error: "+str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need catch the OperationalError.

[exception pymssql.OperationalError](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.OperationalError)

> Raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not
>   necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected
>   disconnect occurs, the data source name is not found, a transaction
>   could not be processed, a memory allocation error occurred during
>   processing, etc. A subclass of DatabaseError.

```
try:
    CURSOR.execute(query)
except OperationalError as e:
    print "OperationalError : {0}".format(e)
```